# How to create a list in two columns with symbols label

Tags: symbols, itemize, tasks

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\scriptsize\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1a
        \item Item 1b
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 2a
        \item Item 2b
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

[image: One column]

I want to put `Item 2` and its subitems in a new column to the right of `Item 1`:

[image: Two columns]

However, I do not know how to achieve it.

I tried using [`tasks`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package but I am not able to:

1. Find the same indentation of the items with the margin or with their descriptions.
2. Move the second item and its subitems to a new column.
3. Find the same symbol of the middle bar that `itemize` has at its second depth level (`\textendash` is a bit shorter).

This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

{\scriptsize\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
    \task Item 1
    {\begin{tasks}[item-indent=2pt](1)
        \task[\textendash] Item 1a
        \task[\textendash] Item 1b
    \end{tasks}}
    \task Item 2
    {\begin{tasks}[item-indent=2pt](2)
        \task[\textendash] Item 2a
        \task[\textendash] Item 2b
    \end{tasks}}
\end{tasks}}

\end{document}
```

[image: What I tried]

Comparison:

[image: Comparison]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using multicol package :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1a
    \item Item 1b
    \end{itemize}
  \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 2a
    \item Item 2b
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I never used `multicols`. Very simple and precise, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Using `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
{\scriptsize
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{outline}
        \1 Item 1
        \2 Item 1a
        \2 Item 1b 
    \end{outline}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{outline}
        \1 Item 2
        \2 Item 2a
        \2 Item 2b 
    \end{outline}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I like [flav's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464071/152550) more because its solution is easier to understand (only for that I accept his solution).

Comment: @manooooh its okay. Here, `minipage` do the same work as `multicolumn`, and the `outline` package is preferable over multiple use of `itemize`. Also `{\scriptsize}` can be replaced by two `\scriptsize` as in flav's answer.